# mac os photos does not sync with icloud / Restoring from icloud stuck / afraid that deletion of photos on mac does not affect icloud

Tags: macos, icloud, photos, data-synchronization, catalina

I try to get my overlarge photos library under control (currently ~220 GB on my SSD).

I am running Catalina 10.15.2 on a 2014 Macbook Pro.

Therefore I deleted a lot of videos and photos. Mainly duplicates, screenshots and so on. But in the end I deleted some 2.000 items which took a couple of hours since I did it manually. I am sonewhat afraid to use duplicate finders. I tried that but found out that for example gemini2 also marked single photos as duplicates.

After I did that two nights ago I checked my icloud to see if the video/ photos had also been deleted there. But nothing happened there. All the duplicate videos are still there. Even now 2 days later nothing changed in the icloud?!

My photos app on mac os is configured like that:
[image: icloud is activated / optimise mac storage is activated]

My understanding ist that deleting a photo in mac os would remove it from my icloud and any of my other devices. Especially since each time I delete an item, photos gives me a warning that the item is going to removed from all devices.

My photos app shows me the message "Restoring from icloud ..." with a ~90% complete progress bar.

[image: Restoring from icloud with a 90% progress bar]

But this progress bar is stuck for the last ~30h or so.

After various restarts and so on I went into the Activity Monitor and canceled all processes connected to photos. Afterwards I restarted the Photos app again and it looked like this:

[image: Restoring from icloud not running and the amount of pictures, videos what it is supposed to be]

The "Restoring from icloud" process is not running and the numbers of videos/ pictures roughly the amount that it should be after I deleted all the duplicates.

After a couple of seconds later the "Restore from icloud" process is again running/ stuck.

My questions:

1) How can I get the sync process running again?

2) Could it be that the photos app is trying to retrieve the deleted photos/ videos from my icloud. The message "restore from icloud" and the higher numbers of vids/ pics seem to imply something like that. If so, how can I prevent that? I want to delete those dupes.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  The speed at which changes on your MBP are reflected in iCloud can vary depending on several factors.  Is your MBP always awake and connected to the internet?  If it sleeps/hibernates that will stop the photo sync.  Also, be sure to check iCloud.com to see if your changes are there.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome.

Do I get you right? Everything ist within normal parameters and I should just wait more time, then the sync will eventually happen?

Comment: I try to keep my MBP up and running all the time. When I look into my Photos app I see a static image of an unmoving progress bar frozen in time.

Comment: If it's been a few days and the progress bar doesn't appear to be moving (or the sync hasn't completed) then my guess is the same as yours: it's stuck.  Are any other applications syncing correctly (Contacts, Calendar, Mail, etc)?